# How to select a selection and fill it with wanted color?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

I have a vector and when I click on it all sections are selected, but I want to select separated sections and fill it with my wanted color or effects. Actually, I can select a section on it by black arrow selection tool using "CTRL + click that section" then I fill color but all the vector is also filled.

Anyone have a solution for me with Illustrator CC?

Answer (score 0):

Select everything and type <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> (compound path > release compound path). It should then work. At the minute, it is being treated as a single (compound) object, hence why fill fills everything.

*I assume this is the problem & the solution; note you may also need to ungroup, possibly several times, depending upon how the original object was built.*